# Altering a function

Tags: 7

I have a Drupal 7 custom modul and a sub module.
In my custom module there is a function: pay($form_state) this implements some if statement these are indentify some payment options.

I would like to altering this whole function with some new payment options from my submodule.

How can I do that? Becouse I can't solve it with drupal_alter, becouse my altered function not run.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Have you tried creating your own hook? [Drupal - Create a Custom Hook for Other Modules to Use](http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/drupal-create-custom-hook-for-other-modules)

Comment: Hi thanks, I have seen this tutorial but to tell you the truth it is not enought for me to understand creating a hook.  I have seen something else that you should put your hooks to .api.php but unfortunately I can't find any complete tutorial to create a custom hook for your module. And I have to use drupal_alter becouse I have to give my hook referencies (&$form_state).